# what scope does a function set to let have?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

let as opposed to var is scoped more tightly than var but I was wondering if it changes the scoping of anonymous functions?

Example:

```
class Foo {
    method1() {
        var scopelessFunc = this.method2;

        // executed in global scope
        scopelessFunc();

        let differentScope = this.method2;

        // what scope is this executed in?  (what does method2 output)
        differentScope();
    }

    method2() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

NOTE: as of today jan 14 to my knowledge let is not fully supported anywhere so I can not go and test this myself.

Comment: `let` only declares where a variable will be visible. No more, no less.

Comment: `this` is still the global object, it has nothing to do with lexical scope. `this` will depend on how you call the function.

Comment: *this* is based on how you call a function, not where it's called from. It's always resolved in the current execution context (except for arrow functions in ES6, which use the outer context's *this*).

Comment: And no, the scope in which a function was called never affected the scope of the executed function itself.

Comment: thank you! cool, I learned something today!
if one of you guys post this as an answer i can accept it or I will just delete the question.

Comment: @dtracers—you can always answer the question yourself based on what you've learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two concepts which have nothing to do with one another. Variable scoping via `let` and `var` just influences the visibility of those variables. The magic keyword `this` is a completely separate mechanism. What `this` refers to depends on how the function was invoked. Both `scopelessFunc()` and `differentScope()` invoke the function in exactly the same way, so there's no difference. If you want to make a difference, you need to change the way you call them:

```
someObj.scopelessFunc()
scopelessFunc.apply(someObj)
```

That's the only thing that influences `this`, and it doesn't matter whether `someObj` or `scopelessFunc` where defined via `var` or `let`.